# Email to include signature

Tags: java, spring

I am using the `AbstractMailMessageSender` to send email from our application to user.
I have extended this class to include the Attachments too.

```
public void sendMessage() throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage msg = sender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
    helper.setTo(this.to);
    helper.setFrom(this.from);
    helper.setSubject(this.subject);
    helper.setText(this.message);
    if (this.cc != null){
        helper.setCc(this.cc);
    }
    if (this.bcc != null){
        helper.setBcc(this.bcc);
    }
    for(String attachment : attachments.keySet()){
        helper.addAttachment(attachment, attachments.get(attachment));
    }
    sender.send(msg);
}
```

I am trying to include a signature with the email. Unfortunately, the class doesnt have a method for signature.

I tried to send it along with the message body but I lose the line breaks and formatting.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: wait, what is the MimeMessageHelper class? Is ist from spring? If so, please tag spring

Comment: The only mention of `AbstractMailMessageSender` on the entire interweb is *this* question.

Comment: the entire interweb and my classpath :)

Comment: Figured it out. I replaced all \r\n with <br> and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the signature is a separate part of an SMTP message.

You will have to set it in the text, and make sure you don't loose formatting (this depends on the content type of your message, and on the text you are setting).

From what I see you are perhaps using the wrong `setText(..)` method. You may have to use `setText(text, true)` to indicate html is used.

Of course, I assumed that if you are using html and formatting, you are using `<br />` for new lines. It turned out not to be the case though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I am using the setText(text,true) All I had to do was change the CRs to <br>

Comment: @Viidhya in what you showed you are not using it. please make sure you are showing real code.